# DFT result using vDSP from Swift from real valued input (Surge implementation)

Tags: ios, swift, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I'm incurring in a non-compatible result within the Surge implementation of the DFT function; I'm using the Surge implementation, which seems straightforward to me.

When I compute the magnitudes for dummy data I get:

```
var xx = [1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
```

> {0.6, 0.082842712474619, 0.2, 0.482842712474619, 0.2,
>   0.482842712474619, 0.2, 0.082842712474619, 0.0, 0.2}

Which just seems wrong following "*if it's real in one domain, it's conjugate symmetric in the other*"

When I do the same thing:

In Mathematica:

```
x = {1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.}
Norm /@ Fourier[x, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]
```

> {0.4, 0.117557, 0.154336, 0.190211, 0.214896, 0., 0.214896, 0.190211,
>   0.154336, 0.117557}

In R:

```
x = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
abs(fft(x)/length(x))
```

> "0.400000" "0.117557" "0.154336" "0.190211" "0.214896" "0.000000"
>   "0.214896" "0.190211" "0.154336" "0.117557"

Also using JTransforms:

```
double[] x = { 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1. };
double[] output = new double[x.length];
DoubleFFT_1D fftDo = new DoubleFFT_1D(x.length);
double[] fft = new double[x.length * 2];
System.arraycopy(x, 0, fft, 0, x.length);
fftDo.realForwardFull(fft);
```

> 0.4 0.11755705045849463 0.1543361918426817 0.19021130325903074 0.21489611417496346 0.0 0.21489611417496346 0.19021130325903074 0.1543361918426817 0.11755705045849463

The Swift implementation in Surge is:

```
public func fft(_ input: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    var real = [Double](input)
    var imaginary = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: input.count)
    var splitComplex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)

    let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(input.count))))
    let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)
    let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(length, radix)
    vDSP_fft_zipD(weights!, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

    var magnitudes = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: input.count)
    vDSP_zvmagsD(&splitComplex, 1, &magnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(input.count))

    var normalizedMagnitudes = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: input.count)
    vDSP_vsmulD(sqrt(magnitudes), 1, [2.0 / Double(input.count)], &normalizedMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(input.count))

    vDSP_destroy_fftsetupD(weights)

    return normalizedMagnitudes
}
```

Am I missing out something obvious?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like your Swift/vDSP code assumes a length which is a power of 2. Try working with N = 16 instead of N = 10.

Comment: That's really an advancement, thanks! With powers of two the result is the same. But what if I want some arbitrary input length?

Comment: Many FFT implementations support only powers of 2 lengths - when you need to use a different size then the typical method is to pad your input data with zeroes up to the next power of 2. This gives valid results, although the frequency domain data is effectively interpolated across the larger no of points.

Comment: So that basically, if I wanted to use such a simple approach (padding), the counterpart is that I'd have to "reinterpolate" it to the original frequency to be comparable with other results i listed. Am i right?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: No, you don't normally need to reinterpolate, although it depends on your specific use case. For most applications you can just work with the frequency domain data in the normal way,e.g. for filtering or spectral analysis,

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your information and patience.

My understanding is that padding gives a coherent solution, but then the values of coefficients could only be comparable to ones coming from an interpolation on the same frequency.

So when comparing to data that comes from other software, the two options are: always use powers of two, or find out a way in Swift/Accelerate to get a "generic" DFT (I'm basicaly investigating the latter) and use an arbitrary frequency

Comment: It's generally better to work with powers of 2 if you can, so pad your vDSP implementation and any other implementations which you want to compare against. Powers of 2 are usually much more efficient any way, so it's win-win unless your use case prevents this approach.

Comment: Note that I've now converted the above comments to an answer below, for the benefit of any future readers.

Comment: thanks Paul, your clarifications were really helpful

Comment: My pleasure - you might find it interesting to read some of the questions and answers with the `[fft]` tag here on SO. Also, to dig deeper there is a more specialised StackExchange site dedicated to DSP: http://dsp.stackexchange.com, which is focussed on DSP theory rather than programming and has lots of good info on FFTs etc, at all levels.

Comment: Thank you for your pointers: I'd have a tour to brush up my rusts!
Very appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Swift/vDSP code assumes a length which is a power of 2. If you try working with N = 16 instead of N = 10 then you should get correct results which will then match other FFT implementations.

Many FFT implementations support only power of 2 lengths - when you need to use a different size then the typical method is to pad your input data with zeroes up to the next power of 2. This gives valid results, although the frequency domain data is effectively interpolated across the larger no of points (it *appears* to have higher frequency resolution than then no of real data points would provide, but this is just a result of the interpolation). An added bonus is that FFT implementations are usually at their most efficient when working with powers of 2, and it's often faster to use a padded power of 2 FFT than a shorter arbitrary size.

Comment: What if we pad remaining cells with a repeatation of array elements from 0 to M where M is 2^k - N ?

Comment: No, don't do that.

Comment: I am having the same issues in that my MATLAB code will give different results than the Swift version, but I was aware of the length being required to be a power of 2. Using a power of 2 as the length does not correct the operation of the code at all.

Comment: @SwiftMatt: post a new question with the relevant code and result data and I'll take a look (be sure to add the [fft] tag and I'll get notified when it's posted).